# Is there a way to alphabetize package.json without installing a package?

Tags: npm

I've been working on lots of old npm packages that have their dependencies all out of order. They're shrinkwrapped packages, so updating dependencies is a bit of work (testing and verifying that the dependency changes didn't break anything), but I'm manually moving some dependencies from the `devDependencies` key to the `dependencies` key, and I don't want to do anything except alphabetize them before I commit. Rather than doing it manually, is there an easy way to programmatically alphabetize them with npm?

Comment: Could you just use your text editor to sort the dependency lines? Sublime Text has built-in support (Edit -> Sort Lines) and IntelliJ has a plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5919

Answer (score 226, accepted):

The [`sort-package-json` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sort-package-json) sorts not only `dependencies` and `devDependencies`, but other keys as well. I know the original questions didn't ask about the other keys, but I think it's cool to have all keys sorted.

You can simply run:

```
npx sort-package-json
```

Example from the package page:

```sh
$ cd my-project

$ cat package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "sort-package-json": "1.0.0",
    "sort-object-keys": "1.0.0"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "my-awesome-project"
}
 
$ npx sort-package-json
package.json is sorted!
 
$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "my-awesome-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "sort-object-keys": "1.0.0",
    "sort-package-json": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

This does not remove the trailing newline like the `npm-sort` package mentioned by Wolfgang.

#### Multiple files

```
$ sort-package-json "my-package/package.json" "other-package/package.json"

$ sort-package-json "package.json" "packages/*/package.json"
```

Comment: you can simply run `npx sort-package-json` if you are using `npm>=5.2.0`

Comment: It works, but it's not the right answer.

Answer (score 132):

Just run `npm remove --save anything` or `npm remove --save-dev whatever` and npm will sort that section, without actually touching any of the content. Of course you should make sure that the package name you pass it (which can be anything, spam your keyboard) isn't in your package.json.

Comment: One-liner: `npm remove --save example; npm remove --save-dev example`

Comment: Shorter: `npm remove -S example; npm remove -D example`

Comment: I love this developer way of doing things without having to rely on some external tools ))

Comment: Even shorter: `npm r -S example; npm r -D example` (`r`, `rm` and `un` are the shortest default aliases of `npm uninstall`)

Comment: This is way easier than installing yet another dependency.

Comment: Not that big fan of less typing if brevity gets in the way of clarity of intent so I'm using a '_should_ never exist' package name, the `script` would then be: `    "misc:sortDeps": "npm rm \_\_hey-npm-plz-sort-my-deps\_\_ --save" `

Comment: With newer versions of `npm`, and default config, it's even simpler: `npm remove anything` (or `npm r anything`). This will sort both, `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 63):

In addition to martias answer, you can just run:

```
npx sort-package-json
```

This won't install it permanently. You need npm >5.2.

Comment: this answer should be on top

Comment: This package will also sort the `"scripts"` section of the package.json. Which may not be desirable for some.

Answer (score 16):

If you're using **WebStorm**, just select the lines you want to sort and click `Edit > Sort Lines`.

And for **VSCode**, highlight the lines, Open the command panel (cmd+shift+p or ctrl+p) and search for "Sort Lines Ascending"

Comment: This will probably malform the JSON, since the last key does not have the trailing comma, and you will have to manually add it.

Comment: WebStorm Edit > Sort Lines doesn't work for me, it broke completely the json file

Comment: For json files the thing would be not to sort the whole file and just select the lines with keys, but ofc this isn't a bulletproof solution it's just a quick built-in suggestion that helps most of the times

Answer (score 10):

I have found the [`npm-sort` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-sort), which seems to work quite well, with the minor niggle that it removes the trailing newline from the `package.json` file.

Comment: I think this should be upvoted. sort-package-json sort everything in package.json but npm-sort only sort dependencies and devDependencies. This maybe most of users need

Comment: Shouldn't be upvoted as the question was about sort without additional package.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to take a look at [fixpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fixpack), a CLI to update your package.json following their (slightly) opinionated order. You can however add a `.fixpackrc` to define your own rules, the defaults are:

- name first
- description second
- version third
- author fourth
- all other keys in alphabetical order
- dependencies and devDependencies sorted alphabetically
- newline at the end of the file

Answer (score 2):

you can simply remove or uninstall a non-existing package from your dependencies

```
npm remove kjkjhkjhkjhkj -f --save
```

or shorter

```
npm r -S
```

other solutions are good but have some drawbacks:

1- sorts other keys which may be unwanted behavior

2- installs external packages such as sort-package-json, even by using `npx sort-package-json`

Comment: Shorter version doesn't work, at least in the current NPM version

Comment: it works with me, at least use the longer one.

Comment: But you miss the package name in shorter version: `npm r kjkjhkjhkjhkj -S` (note that `-S` is true by default, so it's not required in most cases).

Answer (score 2):

"npx sort-package-json" works fine, but if you are using Prettier the best option imho is https://github.com/cameronhunter/prettier-package-json. This is great for formatting your entire package.json files and is easy to use with lint-staged.

in my package.json file I have this script:

```
"scripts": {
    "format:packagejson": "npx prettier-package-json --write ./package.json"
  }
```

If you are using VSCode you could also try this plugin:

Sort package.json
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unional.vscode-sort-package-json

It will sort your package.json files on save. Just add the vscode setting:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
    // Sort package.json keys with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unional.vscode-sort-package-json
    "source.sortPackageJson"
  ],
```

Make sure to add the plugin to your workspace recommendations so everyone in your team will also use the plugin.

There is also this tool if you are using Prettier https://github.com/cameronhunter/prettier-package-json

***Bonus:*** Use add https://npmpackagejsonlint.org to lint your package.json files. I haven't tried this package so I can't recommend it. It sounds like it might work better than the options above, but the setup is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

With newers versions of npm, it's even easier (tested with `7.10.0`, `8.19.4`, `9.7.2` and `10.2.4`):

`npm remove unexisting`

or shorter:

`npm r unexisting`

This will short both, `dependencies` and `devDepencencies`, using any package name that is not in the `package.json` (it's recommended to use a package that doesn't exist, but works with any), as the package will be removed from `package.json` if it is present.

Note that flag `‐‐save` (or `‐S`) is not required, as it is true by default (but you may need to use it if you have for instance `save=false` in your `npmrc` file).

Answer (score -3):

in VS-code there's a good packagesorter ofr the whole json file..

there's also something out there called "sortier" which sorts more, and is awesome.